# Is it possible to show line numbers in markdow Bitbucket wiki?

Tags: markdown, codeblocks, bitbucket, wiki

In a Bitbucket wiki, is it possible to show the line numbers in a block code. Below is an example of what i am looking for.

```
1. <?php
2.     $name = 'Paul';
3.     echo 'Received name is: ' . $name;
4. ?>
```

I am using this code, but i am not getting the line number.

```
 #!php

 <?php

 use evokernel\core\controllers as coreControllers;

 class Cliente extends coreControllers\AbstractController {

 }
```

Comment: As far as I know, no. You could add the line numbers manually or create a picture with your editor of choice and upload the picture instead. I wouldn't recommend neither of them since copying code with line numbers is very annoying. What you should do is: don't put long code examples in a wiki (so no line numbers are needed). If you need to explain the code line by line, take a picture of lines, and label it properly.

Comment: @Matt3o12, I will follow your suggestion, thanks! Please post it as an answer, so i will accept it as the best one.

Comment: For people who stumble here, the line numbers feature is now default in the confluence code blocks. =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no built in feature for that.

### What you could do

- Add the line numbers by hand as you did in your question.
- Create a picture with editor of your choice of the source code and add it to the page.

Although both work (and the second one might even look very pretty and you can customize it a whole lot more), I wouldn't choose either of them.
The problem is, people often copy example code because there too lazy to type it. It is extremely annoying to have line numbers right next to the code.

### What you should do

Don't use line numbers at all. I oft find myself editing example code quite often and adding/removing a new line could break the complete tutorial. Finding and replacing the line numbers is a hassle and you might forget some.
You can avert line numbers by using short examples. You really don't need to post more than ~15 lines of code. The more code you have, the harder to understand.
If you really need to add large code chunks and want to guide the user through, you should split the code into sections. You could add comments with a number and a little explanation.
[Here](http://www.raywenderlich.com/23704/demystifying-ios-application-crash-logs#A%20Sample%20Crash%20Log) is a very good example how Soheil Azarpour did it while he was explaining one of these long hard to understand crash reports. Even though you might not understand what he is talking about, it is worth a look how he solved the issue. Scroll down to "A Sample Crash Log" and look how he group the output and explained it almost line by line below. He didn't need a single line number!